# If-else in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following statement:

```
<div id="someid"  when-scrolled=hasMoreItemsToShow(filteredproducts.length, limit)>
```

**hasMoreItemsToShow()** checks if there are more items remaining in the list to be shown. If it returns true, then the following method is executed:

```
showMoreItems()
```

when-scrolled is a custom directive defined by me which checks if the scroll-bar has reached the end of the page.

So, what I want to do achieve this? That is, on end of scroll event, first check if **hasMoreItemsToShow()** returns true, and if yes, then call **showMoreItems()**

I am very new to Angular, so please excuse me if the question appears naive.

Comment: Could you please add more of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="someid"  when-scrolled=hasMoreItemsToShow(filteredproducts.length, limit) && showMoreItems() >
```

**ShowMoreItems** will only be called if the first part is true

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inline version of `if-else` which optionally allows you to define a fallback function `otherwise()`.

```
<div id="someid"  when-scrolled="hasMoreItemsToShow(filteredproducts.length, limit) ? showMoreItems() : otherwise()">
```